# Visual Studio Code keeps adding enters when copy pasting text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I copy paste something from in Chrome and paste it into the editor for example into.

```
<p></p>
```

It turns into

```
<p>Copied this text from the web
</p>
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: auto formatting?

Comment: may be prittifier extension or the text you try to copy has new line in the end?

Comment: @T0ny1234 With that plugin disabled it still does it sadly

Comment: @RocketNikita Can you explain further what you mean with that?